# SystemExit: 1 using Dash

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I am new to plotly and dash, when i run my code for the second or third time i get the following error. I can guess i am not able to cancel the previous process. (I am using Spyder5 in Anaconda)

Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

- Serving Flask app "prova1" (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: on
  An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1